# Including external libraries using the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline, freebase

Background: I wish to use [freebase suggest](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) in my app.

I intend to add an autocomplete to the `#location` input using coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $("#location").suggest type: "location"
```

Which will be included by the asset pipeline at `require_tree` in my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require modernizr
//= require_tree .
```

Must I copy `suggest.min.js` to `app/assets/javascripts` and require it as

```
//= require suggest.min
```

or can I require it directly from its [publicly available url](http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.js)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can always get it from the CDN by putting it in a view or template.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.js" %>
```